# How do I parse through an inconsistently formatted text file, ignoring unneeded information?

Tags: c#

I have a file that I need to parse through to pull out certain pieces of information. I can figure out how to parse through each line, but have gotten stuck on searching for specific pieces of information. I am not interested in someone finishing this code for me. Instead, I am interested in pointers on where I can go from here.
Here is an example of the code I have written.

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> _arrayLists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = "c:\\test.txt";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        string line;

        while (null !=(line = reader.ReadLine()))
        {
            if (line.ToLower().Contains("disconnected"))
            {
                // needs to continue on search for Disconnected or Subscribed
            }
            else
            {
                if (line.ToLower().Contains("subscribed"))
                {
                    // program needs to continue reading file
                    // looking for and assigning values to
                    // dvd, cls, jhd, dxv, hft
                    
                    // records start at Subscribed and end at ;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

A little bit of explanation of the file. I basically need to pull data existing between the word Subscribed and the first ; i come to. Specifically I need to take the values such as dvd = 234 and assign them to their same variables in the code. Not every record will have the same variables.

Here is an example of the text file that I need to parse through.

```
test information
annoying information
Subscribed      more annoying info
            more annoying info

dvd = 234,
cls = 453,
jhd = 567,

more annoying info
more annoying info

dxv = 456,
hft = 876;

more annoying info

test information
annoying information
Subscribed      more annoying info
            more annoying info

dvd = 234,
cls = 455,

more annoying info
more annoying info

dxv = 456,
hft = 876,
jjd = 768;

more annoying info

test information
annoying information
Disconnected        more annoying info
            more annoying info



more annoying info
```

My thought process was to make sure the program associated all the details between subscribed and the `;` as one record. I think the part that I am confused on is in reading the lines. In my head I see the loop reading the line Subscribed, and then going into a method and reading the next line and assigning the value, and so on until it hits the `;`. Once that was done I am trying to figure out how to tell the program to exit that method, but to continue reading from the line right after the semi-colon. Perhaps I am over thinking this..

Comment: My apologies. I didn't want anyone to do the work for me. I wanted to make sure I was doing what I could and make sure people understood I wasn't being lazy.

Comment: @jason: Did u tried my answer? Have a look on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will never get into an `if` like that:

```
line.ToLower().Contains("Disconnected")
```

Here you convert all the characters to lower case, and then you are trying to find a substring with capital `"D"` in it. The expression above will (almost) always evaluate to false.

Secondly, in order for your application to do what you want to do it needs to track the current parsing state. I'm going to ignore the "Disconnected" bit now, as you have not shown what significance it has.

I'll be assuming that you are trying to find everything between Subscribed and first semicolon in the file. I'll also make a couple of other assumption regarding to what can constitute a string, which I won't list here. These can be wrong, but this is my best guess given the information you've provided.

You program will start in a state "looking for subscription". You already set up the read loop, which is good. In this loop you read lines of the file, and you find one that contains word Subscription.

Once you found such line your parser need to move to "parsing subscription" state. In this state, when you read lines you look for lines like `jjd = 768`, perhaps with a semicolon in the end. You can check if the line match a pattern by using Regular Expressions.

Regular Expressions also can divide match to capturing groups, so that you can extract the name (`jjd`) and the value (`768`) separately. Presences or absence of the semicolon could be another RegEx group.

Note that RegEx is not the only way to handle this, but this is the first that comes to mind.

You then keeping matching the lines to your regex and extracting names and values until you come across the semicolon, at which point you switch back to "looking for subscription" state.

You use the current state, to decide how to process the next read line.

You continue until the end of the file.

Generally you want to read up on parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As with all code solutions to problems there are many possible ways to achieve what you are looking for. Some will work better then others. Below is one way that could help point you in the right direction.

1. You can check if the string starts with a keyword or value such as "dvd" (see [MSDN String.StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx)).
2. If it does then you can split the string into an array of parts (see [MSDN String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)).
3. You can then get the values of each part from the string array using the index of the value you want.
4. Do what you need to with the value retrieved.
5. Continue checking each line for your key business rules (ie. The semicolon that will end the section). Maybe you could check the last character of the string. (see [String.EndsWith)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When processing text files containing semi-structured data, state variables can simplify the algorithm.  In the code below, a boolean state variable `isInRecord` is used to track when a `line` is in a record.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
  public class Program
  {
    private readonly static String _testData = @"
test information
annoying information
Subscribed      more annoying info
            more annoying info

dvd = 234,
cls = 453,
jhd = 567,

more annoying info
more annoying info

dxv = 456,
hft = 876;

more annoying info

test information
annoying information
Subscribed      more annoying info
            more annoying info

dvd = 234,
cls = 455,

more annoying info
more annoying info

dxv = 456,
hft = 876,
jjd = 768;

more annoying info

test information
annoying information
Disconnected        more annoying info
            more annoying info



more annoying info";

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
      /* Create a temporary file containing the test data. */
      var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), Path.GetRandomFileName());
      File.WriteAllText(testFile, _testData);

      try
      {
        var p = new Program();
        var records = p.GetRecords(testFile);

        foreach (var kvp in records)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Record #" + kvp.Key);
          foreach (var entry in kvp.Value)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("  " + entry);
          }
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        File.Delete(testFile);
      }
    }

    private Dictionary<String, List<String>> GetRecords(String path)
    {
      var results = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
      var recordNumber = 0;
      var isInRecord = false;

      using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
      {
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
          line = line.Trim();

          if (line.StartsWith("Disconnected"))
          {
            // needs to continue on search for Disconnected or Subscribed
            isInRecord = false;
          }
          else if (line.StartsWith("Subscribed"))
          {
            // program needs to continue reading file
            // looking for and assigning values to
            // dvd, cls, jhd, dxv, hft

            // records start at Subscribed and end at ;

            isInRecord = true;
            recordNumber++;
          }
          else if (isInRecord)
          {
            // Check if the line has a general format of "something = something".
            var parts = line.Split("=".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (parts.Length != 2)
              continue;

            // Update the relevant dictionary key, or add a new key.
            List<String> entries;
            if (results.TryGetValue(recordNumber.ToString(), out entries))
              entries.Add(line);
            else
              results.Add(recordNumber.ToString(), new List<String>() { line });

            // Determine if the isInRecord state variable should be toggled.
            var lastCharacter = line[line.Length - 1];
            if (lastCharacter == ';')
              isInRecord = false;
          }
        }
      }

      return results;
    }
  }
}
```